# JavaScript: Dropzone.js - Adding File Size and Dimensions to Form Submission

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js, dropzone

I'm testing some example code for Dropzone.js and would like to see if I could get the file size to submit as a form field:

```
var KTFormsDropzoneJSDemos = {
init: function(e) {
    new Dropzone("#kt_dropzonejs_example_1", {
            url: "add/submit/",
            paramName: "file",
            maxFiles: 10,
            maxFilesize: 10,
            addRemoveLinks: !0
        }),
        function() {
            const e = "#kt_dropzonejs_example_3",
                o = document.querySelector(e);
            var r = o.querySelector(".dropzone-item");
            r.id = "";
            var t = r.parentNode.innerHTML;
            r.parentNode.removeChild(r);
            var l = new Dropzone(e, {
                url: "add/submit/",
                parallelUploads: 20,
                maxFilesize: 0.25, // 1 MB
                acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg",
                previewTemplate: t,
                previewsContainer: e + " .dropzone-items",
                clickable: e + " .dropzone-select"
            });
            l.on("addedfile", (function(e) {
                o.querySelectorAll(".dropzone-item").forEach((e => {
                    e.style.display = ""
                }))
            })), l.on("totaluploadprogress", (function(e) {
                o.querySelectorAll(".progress-bar").forEach((o => {
                    o.style.width = e + "%"
                }))
            })), l.on("sending", (function(e) {
                o.querySelectorAll(".progress-bar").forEach((e => {
                    e.style.opacity = "1"
                }))
            })), l.on("complete", (function(e) {
                const r = o.querySelectorAll(".dz-complete");
                setTimeout((function() {
                    r.forEach((e => {
                        e.querySelector(".progress-bar").style.opacity = "0", e.querySelector(".progress").style.opacity = "0"
                    }))
                }), 300)
            }))
        }()
}
};
KTUtil.onDOMContentLoaded((function() {
    KTFormsDropzoneJSDemos.init()
}));
```

The Dropzone.js "[Tips & Tricks](https://docs.dropzone.dev/misc/tips)" page lists an example of how to send the file size, height, and width:

> Dropzone adds data to the file object you can use when events fire. You can access `file.width` and `file.height` if it’s an image,

> If you want to add additional data to the file upload that has to be specific for each file, you can register for the sending event:

```
myDropzone.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
  // Will send the filesize along with the file as POST data.
  formData.append("filesize", file.size);
});
```

I have the "sending" section in the example code under the `#kt_dropzonejs_example_3` section, but I cannot figure out how to append the data like they have using the example code. How can I edit the "sending" code to add the file size as form data?

Comment: The use of commas in declarations and to split statements, the mixing of `var` and `const` and use of IIFE makes this code rather uncomfortable for me. There's technically nothing wrong with this but it is a unique style that is quite counter to the defacto norms and I'm curious if this is a personal coding style that has been developed or if there are other reasons for this particular style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the example, you should accept the other parameters when you handle the `sending` event:

```
l.on("sending", (function(file, xhr, formData) {
    o.querySelectorAll(".progress-bar").forEach((e => {
        e.style.opacity = "1"
    }));
    formData.append("filesize", file.size);
})),
```

Per my comment about formatting, my personal preference would be for the code to look something like this:

```
dropzoneExample3.on("sending", (file, xhr, formData) => {
    dropzoneElement.querySelectorAll(".progress-bar").forEach(element => element.style.opacity = "1");
    formData.append("filesize", file.size);
});
```